# I need to parse xml with XMLparser and swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse a xml file from a server with XMLparser in swift,

I have a var m_items that is a NSMutableArray and a CItemData object that has

```
  var m_id:String = ""
  var m_type:CLong = CLong(0)
  var m_title:String = ""
  var m_description:String = ""
  var m_data:String = ""

override init()
{
    super.init();

}

init(id: String, title:String, type:CLong) {
    self.m_id = id;
    self.m_title = title;
    self.m_type = type;
```

this is the xml with a items root a item id and some values like title, description and data.

```
<items>
  <item id="1" type="1">
    <title>
      <![CDATA[ Definition of Hacker ]]>
    </title>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[ Description 1 ]]>
    </description>
    <data>
      <![CDATA[ Data 1 ]]>
    </data>
  </item>
</items>
```

I'm trying to parse like this, but I don't understand how to use didstartelement correctly. Any help? My code is from an example but doesn't fits with my needs. The problem is

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
        {

            var attr:String = ""

            if(elementName == "items")
            {
                self.m_root = CItemData();
                self.m_last_node = self.m_root;
            }
            else if(elementName == "item")
            {
                attr = attributeDict["id"]!

                let item:CItemData = CItemData()

                item.m_id.setObject(attr , forKey: "id" as NSCopying)

                self.m_root?.m_id.add(item)

                self.m_last_item = item;
                self.m_last_node = item;


            }
            else if(elementName == "child")
            {

                attr = attributeDict["id"]!

                let child:CItemData = CItemData()

                child.m_type.setObject(attr , forKey: "id" as NSCopying)

                self.m_last_item?.m_type.add(child)

                self.m_last_node = item;


            }


        }

            func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

                if(elementName == "title")
                {

                    self.m_last_node?.m_title = self.m_last_string
                }
                else if(elementName == "description"){
                    self.m_last_node?.m_description = self.m_last_string
                }
                else if(elementName == "data"){
                    self.m_last_node?.m_data = self.m_last_string
                }

            }

            func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
            {
                self.m_last_string = string;
            }
        }
```

Comment: is your class set up as a delegate properly?

Comment: thanks for answer Joakim, I set the XMLParserDelegate